# Помогите настроить columns или подобрать альтернативу

Tags: html, css

помогите, пожалуйста, не могу решить такую проблему:
У меня есть ul список в который динамически записуються li, нужно что бы создавались колонки 4, решил использовать свойство columns, но тогда колонки выставляются так:

```
1          4          7          10
2          5          8
3          6          9
```

А нужно так:

```
1          2          3          4    
5          6          7          8    
9          10
```

При этом все одного размера, что бы если один из элементов списка был больше, то нижние строки списка все равно были на одном уровне, а не гдето выше, а где то ниже...
Вот код: 
HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul id="menu">
</ul>//куда вставляется контент

<div style="display:none" id="template">
<div class="elements" >
    <li class="#" data-class>
        <a href="#" data-id class="open_modal"><img  src="#" data-url-small title="подробнее" /> </a>
        <h1 data-name-first class="firstName"></h1>
        <p>вес: <span data-weight></span> гр. цена <span data-price></span> грн.</p>
        <button class="buy"><p><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Хочу!</p></button>
        <div class="forModal" id="#" data-link style="display:none">
            <div class="forClone">
            <img src="#" data-url-big title="подробнее" />
            <h1 data-name-second></h1>
            <p data-consist></p>
            <button class="buy"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Хочу!</button> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div> //заполняемый динамически контент
```

CSS:

```
 .menu li {
list-style-type: none; 
width: 90%;
text-align: center;
color: red;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

  .menu ul{
-webkit-columns: 4; 
-moz-columns: 4; 
columns: 4;
}

.menu  img { max-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none:
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Через `float: left`, либо `display: inline-block`

`columns` от слова столбцы (колонки), я думаю тут все понятно

Comment: Тогда у меня сїезжают колонки... У меня нету фиксированого размера, без float: left все работает красиво, с ним все едет

Comment: @VaCool, покажите код, так сложно что то сказать

Comment: Отправил код СSS и HTML

Comment: @VaCool, меняйте width: 90%;

Comment: Спасибо, самый простой стособ оказался и самым эффективным). Все заработало и автоматом масштабируется)